# ¿Cómo meter un valor de una celda dentro de los corchetes de una referencia estructurada?

Tags: excel

Lo he preguntado en stackoverflow en inglés, pero no me entienden o no me explico bien o algo así.

Estoy tratando de cambiar el valor dentro de los corchetes de una referencia estructurada. Un ejemplo:

```
BUSCARV(C12;HORARIOS_2022[CK]:HORARIOS_2022[07/01/2022];190;FALSO)
```

Quiero convertirlo en:

```
BUSCARV(C12;HORARIOS_2022[CK]:HORARIOS_2022[C15];190;FALSO)
```

Donde `HORARIOS_2022` es el nombre de una de las hojas y `C15` (la celda) contiene 01/07/2022.

Esto es debido a que necesito hacer esto (o algo relacionado) ya que tengo 31 hojas iguales a las imágenes, y cada una tiene una celda donde está el día (01/07/2022 en este caso), y esta celda es la que marcaría la última columna del rango (01/07/2022. Hay una columna que se llama así en `HORARIOS_2022`)

Quiero usar `C15` en lugar de `07/01/2022` dentro de los corchetes `[]` (Lo siento, no puedo explicarlo mejor).

`INDIRECTO()` y `"["&C15&"]"` no funcionan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Me he dado cuenta de los guiones, pero los he corregido)

¡Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estabas bastante cerca y tu aproximación con INDIRECTO era la mejor opción pero no lo estabas usando bien. Y luego está el tema de los encabezados. Vamos a ver si me explico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi BUSCARV funciona perfectamente:

```
=BUSCARV(C12;INDIRECTO("HORARIOS_2022[[CK]:["&TEXTO(C15;"dd/mm/aaaa")&"]]");5;FALSO)
```

Para empezar, cuando usas INDIRECTO la referencia tiene que ser texto. Con lo cual tenías que concatenar. De hecho la solución en circunstancias normales sería:

```
INDIRECTO("HORARIOS_2022[[CK]:["&C15&"]]")
```

Pero sucede una cosa más y es que estás usando fechas como encabezados. En Excel, las fechas, por defecto, son números. Concretamente, el 1 representa 01/01/1900, el 2 es 02/01/1900, etc. Hoy 20/07/2022 en realidad para Excel es 44762.

Dicho esto, los encabezados de una tabla siempre son leídos como texto, con lo que el valor 20/07/2022 ya no es leído como un número sino como un texto. Y entonces tu BUSCARV combinado con INDIRECTO falla porque el valor que hay en la celda C15 es un número y eso no lo encuentra en los encabezados porque son textos!!!!

Entonces hay que hacer una función adicional y forzar a Excel a que lea la celda C15 como texto. Eso explica esta parte de la fórmula:

`TEXTO(C15;"dd/mm/aaaa")`

Ahora combinamos todo en la función final y obtenemos la fórmula que sí funciona:

```
=BUSCARV(C12;INDIRECTO("HORARIOS_2022[[CK]:["&TEXTO(C15;"dd/mm/aaaa")&"]]");5;FALSO)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dios, que buena pinta tiene lo que has explicado! Lo pruebo ahora mismo

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con

```
BUSCARV(C12;HORARIOS_2022[CK]:HORARIOS_2022!C15;190;FALSO)
```

Sino revisa la estructura:

Es dificil entenderla sin tener el excel, la estructura es la siguiente :

```
BUSCARV(valor-buscar, tabla-conjunto, col-índice-núm[, [rango-buscar-marcador]])
```

En tu caso el valor a buscar seria el de **C12**.

La posicion a buscar entiendo que es **de HORARIOS_2022[CK] a HORARIOS_2022!C15**

Lo que quedaria en el cuadro del BUSCARV seria la posicion **190** de la busqueda

Y que intentas una **busqueda exacta**.

No entiendo la busqueda de HORARIOS_2022[CK] a HORARIOS_2022!C15, no seria mas facil seleccionar con esa busqueda la tabla entera? me explico:

```
BUSCARV(C12;HORARIOS_2022!$C$12:HORARIOS_2022!$C$15;190;FALSO)
```

De esta manera busca en los campos C12 a C15, esto es editable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, pero me aparece `#¡REF!`

Comment: @Jotaerre editada la respuesta

Comment: La cuestión es que tengo muchísimas hojas (del 1 al 31, para completar un mes completo) y lo que busco es que en cada hoja esté el día de cada mes, y dependiendo de este día cambie el rango.

En `HORARIOS 2022` tengo varias columnas (del 01/07/2022 al 31/07/2022) y, claro, lo que busco es que esto sea cambiante (el 190 he conseguido cambiarlo para que esto vaya bien)